# How to use javax mail with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I've searched alot about that but didn't find any answer that using thymeleaf template with javax.mail every example is using  spring-boot-starter-mail

Any of you has a solution for that ?

this is the code i'm using :

```
package com.journaldev.mail;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Session;

public class SimpleEmail {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("SimpleEmail Start");
        
        String smtpHostServer = "smtp.example.com";
        String emailID = "email_me@example.com";
        
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHostServer);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        
        EmailUtil.sendEmail(session, emailID,"SimpleEmail Testing Subject", "SimpleEmail Testing Body");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

public class ThymeleafEmail {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {

    // Set mail properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    // Get the Session object
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

    // Prepare the Thymeleaf template
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");

    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);

    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("name", "John Doe");

    String processedTemplate = templateEngine.process("email_template", context);

    // Create a message
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@example.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("to@example.com"));
    message.setSubject("Test email with Thymeleaf template");
    message.setContent(processedTemplate, "text/html");

    // Send the message
    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Email sent successfully!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?